# Second Borel–Cantelli lemma intuition

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Currently I am reading Rick Durett's Probability Theory and Examples. I am confused by the following theorem.

**Theorem 2.3.7. The second Borel-Cantelli lemma.** 
If the events $A_n$ are independent then $$\sum_n P(A_n) =∞ $$ implies $$ P(A_n \space i.o.) = 1 $$
Where $$ P(A_n \space i.o.) = P(\space limsup \space A_n ) $$ $$ limsup \space A_n = \{ \omega | \omega \in A_n\ for\ and\ infinite\ amount\ of\ A_n\ 's \}$$

So, if for example I take $A_n = [0, 1/n)$ in the following probability space $([0,1], \sigma([0,1]), \lambda)$ then by the lemma $P(limsupA_n) = 1$ but $ limsupA_n = \{0\} $ which gives rise to a contradiction.

Where am I mistaken ?  I can't assume that $A_n$'s are independent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not independent: since $A_n \supseteq A_{n+1}$ and $P(A_n) \ne 1$ for $n > 1$ we have
$$P(A_n \cap A_{n+1}) = P(A_{n+1}) \ne P(A_n) \cdot P(A_{n+1}), \qquad n > 1.$$

Comment: Ah.. I should probably get some rest :) Thanks